# cant show data in table

Tags: php, html, database

I was trying to show up the data from my databse to an html table. But when I run it it doesn't show the database data. It just shows up like this, **'.$res['name'].'**. I think I have done a silly mistake but couldn't find out.

Edit: Srry it was a dumb mistake. I had saved my file in .html extension, I saved it in .php now it is working fine. Thanks everyone.
My view.php file:

```
<?php
include_once ("config.php");

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT* FROM `testing` ORDER BY `id` DES");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
 <?php
while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$res['name'].'</td>'; // here it just shows up like '.$res['name'].'</td>' , instead of showing data.
    echo '<td>'.$res['email'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$res['phone'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>

</table>

 


    
</body>
</html>
```

My config.php file:

```
<?php

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "datatest";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpwd = "";

$mysqli = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpwd,$dbname);
?>
```

Comment: If you're seeing PHP code on the screen like that I wonder if PHP is not installed, or not configured properly in your webserver, or whether you're not accessing the page in the correct way via HTTP

Comment: Once you fix that you should pay attention to the mistake in your query as mentioned in user27976's answer below

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM `testing` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
```

add space before select and *, "Des" incorrect "DESC" correct

Answer (score -2):

You may need to set the `mysqli_fetch_array` `$mode` `MYSQLI_ASSOC` to specify you want an associative array.

PHP

```
while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
```

Comment: It defaults to `MYSQLI_BOTH`, so will work without it.

Answer (score -2):

The fetch_array() / mysqli_fetch_array() function fetches a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both.

If you want to fetches a result row as an associative array,

**while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))**

If you want the result in a numeric array,

**while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM))**

Otherwise, you want both [**MYSQLI_BOTH (this is the default)**]

**while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH))**